# Text direction and pluralization dataset

Tags: ruby, dataset, pluralize

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project, in which I need to get the text direction and the plural form for different languages. Something like:

```
en: { plural_keys: [:one, :other], text_dir: :left_to_right },
sk: { plural_keys: [:one, :few, :other], text_dir: :left_to_right },
...
```

Is there any free dataset I could extract this information from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [CLDR - Unicode Common Locale Data Repository](http://cldr.unicode.org/index) which contains all data I need. It is also available as the [twitter_cldr gem](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-cldr-rb).